# Handling multiple interrupts with FreeRTOS on STM32

Tags: arm, stm32, interrupt, interrupt-handling, freertos

My MCU based control system must check 18 switch contact status fastly. I will use STM32F7 MCU and it has maximum 16 int. handler. So I have been decided to use IO expendar IC and divided groups. Now I have 12 IO external interrupt and 2 more interrupt comes from IO expander. In addition FreeRTOS will has ethernet, uart and canbus tasks for communications. Interrupts are very critical for system. There is milisecond difference between them and I have to detect all pins status correctly. I need and expert advice for this situation.

My questions are :

- Is this a proper way ? Using 14 external interrupt onFreeRTOS that handles multiple communication task
- Is there any better way for it ?

Comment: You mention "millisecond difference". That's rather relaxed. You can easily use a timer that triggers an interrupt every millisecond and then checks all switches. No need for additional parts or many interrupt handlers.

Comment: You say create a task that has a loop for cheking all GPIO status every 0.5ms or 1 ms. At the back end other tasks (ethernet, uarts etc) runs clearly ?

Comment: What do you mean by "other tasks run clearly"?

Comment: My mcu has 1 core so in real world tasks do not run simultaneously. A lots of interrupting may be hurt ethernet or other task I think

Comment: Assuming your MCU runs with 50 MHz or higher, I don't expect that checking 18 GPIOs takes more than 0.05ms. So it's an negligible load even if it is run once every ms.

Comment: 1ms is pretty close to the default FreeRTOS scheduler clock of 1kHz. So you can use a hardware timer that check the input level, and then send message or mail to a sleeping task if you need any process. I use this system a lot in my design. If you need to insure a "< 1ms reaction", maybe you can handle all the stuff in the interrupt if it's light and fast.

Comment: EXTI interrupts will have no impact on system performance. But much better is just to have interrupt every 1ms checking the status of the pins. For F7 it is not noticeable. miliseconds reaction is an eternity for this system. If you say 1us or 0.5us - the story would be a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Using an IO expander seems like the wrong approach to your problem (additional complexity and cost). You don't have to assign a dedicated ISR to each pin. Just read the GPIOx_IDR register after any GPIO interrupt, then check the relevant bits [STM32 Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00224583-stm32f76xxx-and-stm32f77xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)